# gobject.timeout_add() not working after calling gtk.threads_init() on windows xp

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

Following simple code will hang forever on windows XP, and the "check dialog" text is never outputted to console. The window created in the code showed but is blocked (when I move mouse into the window area, the mouse pointer is always a "loading" icon)

While same code works well on Windows 7

Runtime details: Windows XP SP3, python 2.7.5, pytgtk-2.24-allinone

```
import gtk
import gobject

def checkDialog():
  print 'check dialog'
  return True

gobject.timeout_add(500, checkDialog)
gtk.threads_init()
w = gtk.Window()
w.show()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Tested on Debian sid, it works. Window is showed and 'check dialog' mesasges is printed out to console.

Comment: @LiuLang, Did you test it on Windows XP?

Comment: sorry, but I have no Windows system. :-(

Comment: @LiuLang, sorry that I saw "Window is showed" as "WINDOWS is showed"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally one guy from irc channel #pygtk gives me the answer:

I need use **gobject.threads_init()** instead of **gtk.threads_init()**

A complete solution can be found here [pygtk gobject.timeout_add() won’t work after calling gtk.threads_init() on windows xp](http://redino.net/blog/2013/06/pygtk-gobject-timeout_add-wont-work-after-calling-gtk-threads_init-on-windows-xp/)